# Change Culture Works On Local But Not Working On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm changing cultureinfo with a list using httppost and cookies it works very well on my local test but when i upload it to my IIS it's not working..

```
 [HttpPost]
        public  IActionResult ChangeLanguage(string language , string returnUrl)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
            if(CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture != null) CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
            if(CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture != null) CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture.ClearCachedData();
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(language)),
                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1)}

                );
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

HTML

```
    <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">


        <form asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" id="langform">
            <input type="text" id="langinput" hidden name="language" value="" />
            <li onclick="SubmitAndChange('tr')" class="lang-li"><div class="flag flag-tr"></div> Türkçe</li>
            <li onclick="SubmitAndChange('en')" class="lang-li"><div class="flag flag-us"></div> English</li>

        </form>

    </ul>
```

Javascript

```
      function SubmitAndChange(lang) {
            $("#langinput").val(lang);
            $("#langform").submit();
        }
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` just changes the culture of the current thread. Maybe you should set [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netframework-4.8)? - _"Gets or sets the default culture for threads in the current application domain."_

Comment: It is still same

Comment: Is the browser following the redirect or did it just pull the last page cached locally? You can use Fiddler to see if the redirect actually loads the page or just recognizes a redirect to a page that hasn't changed and thus loads the locally cached copy.

Comment: I really dont know how to use Fiddler but I dont think so , I submit the form with javascript and I tried to get culture and type it on index with ViewBag it still says "en" even if I changed it to "tr"
If it helps i updated my post with html&javascript

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/mar/27/auto-selecting-cultures-for-localization-in-aspnet

Comment: Did you get any error message? you could use some visual studio mode debug or use the browser developer tool to check is there any detail about the issue.

Comment: No there is no error message it just not switching between the cultures.

@DavidTansey My man, this article for ASP.NET not for CORE version. It has old files, old things.

Comment: did you try to debug the asp.net application from the iis?[link](https://forums.asp.net/post/5318384.aspx)

Comment: I figured it out , the cookies are the issues. In local there is a cookie called
.AspNetCore.Culture 
But this is not apperears on IIS. I couldn't find a way to fix it.